# VBS Script - Need to change msgbox to echo

Tags: vbscript, output, echo, msgbox

I'm having a hard time converting this script to an echo instead of a msgbox output.

I need to output to go into a text file in C:\key.log instead of a message box with the key.

Anyone know how to go about this? Thanks!

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
MsgBox ConvertToKey(WshShell.RegRead("HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\DigitalProductId"))

Function ConvertToKey(Key)
Const KeyOffset = 52
i = 28
Chars = "BCDFGHJKMPQRTVWXY2346789"
Do
Cur = 0
x = 14
Do
Cur = Cur * 256
Cur = Key(x + KeyOffset) + Cur
Key(x + KeyOffset) = (Cur \ 24) And 255
Cur = Cur Mod 24
x = x -1
Loop While x >= 0
i = i -1
KeyOutput = Mid(Chars, Cur + 1, 1) & KeyOutput
If (((29 - i) Mod 6) = 0) And (i <> -1) Then
i = i -1
KeyOutput = "-" & KeyOutput
End If
Loop While i >= 0
ConvertToKey = KeyOutput
End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this :

```
Option Explicit
Dim WshShell,RegKey,WindowsKey,LogFile,fso
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
RegKey = "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\DigitalProductId"
WindowsKey = ConvertToKey(WshShell.RegRead(RegKey))
LogFile = "c:\key.log"
if fso.FileExists(LogFile) Then 
    fso.DeleteFile LogFile
end If
MsgBox WindowsKey,VbInformation,WindowsKey 
Call WriteLog(WindowsKey,LogFile)
WshShell.Run LogFile
'***********************************************************************************************************
Function ConvertToKey(Key)
    Const KeyOffset = 52
    Dim i,Chars,Cur,x,KeyOutput
    i = 28
    Chars = "BCDFGHJKMPQRTVWXY2346789"
    Do
        Cur = 0
        x = 14
        Do
            Cur = Cur * 256
            Cur = Key(x + KeyOffset) + Cur
            Key(x + KeyOffset) = (Cur \ 24) And 255
            Cur = Cur Mod 24
            x = x -1
        Loop While x >= 0
        i = i -1
        KeyOutput = Mid(Chars, Cur + 1, 1) & KeyOutput
        If (((29 - i) Mod 6) = 0) And (i <> -1) Then
            i = i -1
            KeyOutput = "-" & KeyOutput
        End If
    Loop While i >= 0
    ConvertToKey = KeyOutput
End Function
'*************************************************************************************************************
Sub WriteLog(strText,LogFile)
    Dim fs,ts 
    Const ForAppending = 8
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fs.OpenTextFile(LogFile,ForAppending,True)
    ts.WriteLine strText
    ts.Close
End Sub
'**************************************************************************************************************
```

Comment: This is awesome, I ended up using this script instead as it opens the text file after it extracts the Windows key for the user. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The code below replaces the echo statement with a call to the  [FileSystemObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d6dw7aeh%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) (FSO).  This object can add, move, change, create, or delete folders (directories) and files on the Web server or desktop.   The method we are particularly interested is [CreateTextFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5t9b5c0c(v=vs.84).aspx).

```
DIM fso, NewsFile, WshShell

Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set write2File = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\key.log", True)
write2File.WriteLine(ConvertToKey(WshShell.RegRead("HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\DigitalProductId")))
write2File.Close

Function ConvertToKey(Key)
Const KeyOffset = 52
i = 28
Chars = "BCDFGHJKMPQRTVWXY2346789"
Do
Cur = 0
x = 14
Do
Cur = Cur * 256
Cur = Key(x + KeyOffset) + Cur
Key(x + KeyOffset) = (Cur \ 24) And 255
Cur = Cur Mod 24
x = x -1
Loop While x >= 0
i = i -1
KeyOutput = Mid(Chars, Cur + 1, 1) & KeyOutput
If (((29 - i) Mod 6) = 0) And (i <> -1) Then
i = i -1
KeyOutput = "-" & KeyOutput
End If
Loop While i >= 0
ConvertToKey = KeyOutput
End Function
```

Comment: I get the following error when I run this .VBS script. - Char: 1
Error: Object required: "WshShell"
Code: 800A01A8
Source: Microsoft VBScript runtime error

Comment: He forgot to add this line : Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell"), 
so if you add this line it shoud works ;)

Comment: @WorkSmarter and you deserve from me a +1 ;)

Comment: @WorkSmarter I used this script as a side option to work in the background, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

```
Wscript.echo "message"
```

outputs a msgbox when run with wscript and echos to STDOUT when run with cscript in a command prompt.

```
cmd /c cscript //nologo c:\somepath\somefile.vbs > file.txt
```

Comment: So you only need to replace `msgbox` with `wscript.echo` and start it correctly.